# Interpretation of Figure - biofunctionalization

Tags: physical-chemistry, biochemistry, fluorescence

In [this paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/nl2045414?prevSearch=Painting%2bwith%2bbiomolecules%2bat%2bthe%2bnanoscale%253A%2bbiofunctionalization&searchHistoryKey=) on page 1985 they say:

> Fluorescence analysis confirmed that enhanced protein binding at higher electron dose depends only to a small extent on the slight increase in the lateral dimensions of the nanodeposits but to a much larger degree on their height (Figure 4E)
>
> [image]
>
> The amount of adsorbed IgG-Cy3 is largely independent of the actual area of the nominal 100 nm islands but scales with the height of the nanodeposits.

I don't understand this yet: why do I see that the fluorescence is proportional to area in this figure?

Answer (score 1):

The amount of adsorbed protein is proportional to the area of the 100 nm islands. Figure 4E proves it. The authors misinterpreted their own figure.